# Accessing files on a Synology Diskstation via a local IP

Tags: webserver, intranet, file-sharing, synology

I have a Synology Diskstation with a number of shared folders including a folder with a large number of images which I've organized via Photostation.

I also have a virtual machine on the NAS which is running as a webserver.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to access the images through the webserver using http.

example: `http:DiskstaitonIP/shared_folder/images/folder_A/image_1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to come up with was to install Web Station, and configure it to the base directory.